# Solr won't find some results for no apparent reason

Tags: django, search, solr, django-haystack

Please look at this search:

http://astrobin.com:8983/solr/select/?q=Avalon+Linear

In the page, search for `Avalon Linear`. Note how the text goes like this:
*... Avalon Linear FR Zeiss ...*

So I suppose that a search for `Avalon Linear FR` should return the same, instead it returns nothing!

http://astrobin.com:8983/solr/select/?q=Avalon+Linear+FR

Okay, then why would a search for `Avalon Linear Zeiss` work instead?

http://astrobin.com:8983/solr/select/?q=Avalon+Linear+Zeiss

Is there something special about the word `FR`? If it's ignored because too short, then it the result should still be there.

Other searches also give trouble. Take this:

http://astrobin.com:8983/solr/select/?q=TSAPO65Q

Search the page for `Teleskop-Service`. It's there, but a search for `Teleskop-Service` yields no results:

http://astrobin.com:8983/solr/select/?q=Teleskop-Service

By the way, if you aren't confused enough, I don't have this problem on my development machine, but only on the production server! Both systems are running the same software, as far as I can tell!

Any idea of what might be wrong?

Comment: You will probably have to post relevant bits from your schema.xml and solr-config.xml for anyone to have a chance of helping you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded from Solr 3.6.1 to 4.0.0-BETA and rebuilt the schema, and the problem is solved.